# Hybris Backoffice Action Validation Success and Error Messages

Tags: customization, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Need help for custom backoffice extension to design an action class.
I need to create an action class for a backoffice wizard 'NEXT' button. When the NEXT button is clicked after filling in the details, these must be validated from the response of the REST API's and based on that the SUCCESS AND ERROR POPUP messages need to be displayed and also the data must be saved in the Database. Can any one please help me with the basic java code for this?

Comment: Start from here. https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/6.7.0.0/en-US/ab77d455c4fc4472bcbfdfaa4a86a7d4.html

Comment: Not helpful..already tried this!

Comment: Ok did you try implementing Custom Button with Custom FlowActionHandler?. Check out this. https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8b87f564866910148793a7aec951a38f.html